# Python: Writing into file fails without error - getting an empty file

Tags: python-3.x

This code seems to be working fine and the console is giving me exactly what I need without any errors.  However, when I try to open it up with excel it gives me an empty file.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('aapl_analyst_estimates', 'w', newline= '')
writer = csv.writer(f)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/analystestimates').read(), 'lxml')

tbody = soup('table', {'class':'snapshot'})[0].find_all('tr')

for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    writer.writerow(cols)
    print(cols)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. I get the following output:

```
['Number of Ratings:', '41', 'Current Quarters Estimate:', '4.17']
['FY Report Date:', '9 / 2019', "Current Year's Estimate:", '11.99']
["Last Quarter's Earnings:", '2.91', 'Median PE on CY Estimate:', '12.88']
['Year Ago Earnings:', '11.75', 'Next Fiscal Year Estimate:', '13.34']
['', '', 'Median PE on Next FY Estimate:', '11.37']
```

Comment: I'm sorry — I wasn't being more thorough with my query.  The output is fine, but when I open it up with Excel, it gives me an empty file.

Comment: It opens up fine with LibreOffice in Linux. It could be the extension issue with Excel on Windows. Try renaming the file to **aapl_analyst_estimates.csv**.

Comment: Simple as that!  Thank you very much!